# How do i Bootstrap 4 menu nav like on components site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

before starting: My english is very poor therefore forgive my typos

I would like to build a menu that behavaves exactly like on the bootsrap components page with the difference that it should appear on the RİGHT SİDE: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

I am create a navbar and i fixed-top this navbar but navbar overlapping my other items. At first i solved by add a few 
 items. Later i added a float menu and i faced this problem again. I add a few image for your understanding [image]

[image]

I tried CSS and i add body{padding-top: 30px;} but it is not work. yes it leaves a space but when I come to the float menu I still have the same problem

```
<div class="navbar  navbar-expand-md fixed-top border">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand ml-3">
        LOGO
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ExampleNavbar">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ExampleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ml-3" style="font-size: x-large;">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ml-3" style="font-size: x-large;">News</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link ml-3 " style="font-size: x-large;">Home</a>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="ExampleNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-3">
            <a href="" class="nav-item nav-link ml-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login"
                style="font-size: x-large;"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>
                Login</a>
            <a href="" class="nav-item nav-link ml-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#register"
                style="font-size: x-large;"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
                Register</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

your nav bar is transparent , add background color in the navbar

here im using the bootstrap class for making the navbar sky blue

```
bg-primary
```

Comment: actually my navbar is dark(bg-dark). I did transparent for your understanding my problem

Comment: can you please explain what is your exact problem is ?

Comment: you can use the z-index property to set the order of the element

Comment: I would like to build a menu that behavaves exactly like on the bootsrap components page with the difference that it should appear on the RİGHT SİDE: http://getbootstrap.com/components/